# Find minimum value between each cell between two matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices with the following dimensions:

```
A = [61X50] 
B = [61X39]
```

I need to find the minimum value between each corresponding cell between these two matrices and put them in an array C. If there is a missing value (since A has 50 columns and B has 39) - the value from array A should be taken into consideration.

What would be the best way to achieve this in MATLAB ?

Edit:

Here's an example

Say `A = [3 X 3] = [ 1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3]`
and `B = [3 X 2] = [ 0 0; 0 1; 1 2]`

Array C should hold: `[ 0 0 1; 0 1 2; 1 2 3]` (Comparing each value in A and B column wise)

Comment: Create a small example with sample matrices.

Comment: Updated with example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just preallocate `C` with the values of `A` and so the values that are missing in `B` will automatically be the values of `A`. Then you can use the `min`-function of matlab to find the minima that ou are looking for. It would look like this:

```
C=A;
C(:,1:size(B,2))=min(A(:,1:size(B,2)),B)
```